# Track submit event in new window javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I open new window with javascript. I mean function `window.open`. I know that I have object of this window. This new window has `<form>` with checkbox and submit button. So I wonder can I track submit form event and check if checkbox was checked in this new window.

```
window.open('http:some_external_url','new_window','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')
```

And form in new window:

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='somename' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit_button' />
</form>
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: give a name to your window and get the variables from that.

Comment: if the window is loaded from the same origin the you can write event handlers to that

Comment: Description was updated. Please look at it.

Comment: whether the page opening the window and the content loaded in the window are from the same origin

Comment: unfortunately content of the new window are not from my site and url of this window is external.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Surprisingly questions of this kind (cross origin) are coming up too frequently these days. Do you know of a canonical where these questions could be duped to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if the page opening the window and the page that is opened are from the same origin...

```
var win = window.open('form.html', 'formwin');
win.addEventListener('submit', function () {
    console.log('parent: submit')
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aBc8gj2kRTi6DL8uONKa?p=preview)

If they are not, the the browser security policy won't allow you to access the contents of the new window.

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important
- [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)